# Load pictures from directory into array

Tags: perl, unix, grep

I'd like to load all pictures from directory and save them into array.

```
@files = `ls $ARGV[0] | grep -i -E jpe?g|gif|png$`;
```

This line gives me an error: `Final $ should be \$ or $name`

```
@files = `ls $ARGV[0] | grep -i -E \'jpe?g|gif|png$\'`;
```

This line works, but it also loads picture "img.jpg.bmp" and I that is not what I want, and even loads directories, which is secondary but also bad. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 for [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317221/load-pictures-from-directory-into-array#comment23365344_16317351) *"why is using shell so sad?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the shell to read directories or to `grep` is kind of sad

```
use autodie;
opendir my $dir, $ARGV[0];
my @files = grep !/\A\.\.?\z/ && /\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)\z/, readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
```

(we have to manualy filter out the current dir `.` and parent directory `..`. `\A` is like `^` and `\z` is a bit like `$`, but always matches at string ends)

The problem with your `` `command` `` was that it has the interpolation semantics of a double quoted string. The `$` *always* signifies that the next word or character is a variable name (with an exception for regexes). The `` $` `` would be the prematch variabele, but Perl is smart enough to see that you don't want that. The solution your error message suggested is escaping the `$`:

```
`grep -i -E jpe?g|gif|png\$` # … and it meant this.
# It still thinks gif and png are commands
`grep -i -E '(jpe?g|gif|png)\$'` # regex correctly quoted on shell level
```

Surrounding with single quotes is only helpful on the shell level, not on the Perl level, where the error message originated.

In regexes, the end-of-line assertion `$` is just a normal atom like `p` or `[abc]`. It is not an operator, unlike `()` or `|` or `[]`. Therefore you have to force correct precedence with parens. See the regex in my proposed Perl solution above how this is done.

Comment: @chriemmy Using Perl builtins is more verbose, but it only uses one process instead of three (→ performance). Using Perl builtins is safer: Consider `$ARGV[0]` being `dir with spaces` or `; rm -rf *; echo pwned.jpg`. Using Perl builtins and modules is more portable. Pure-Perl code will run on Linux, OSX and Windows without modifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function for get a list of files and filter them with [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html). e.g.:

```
my(@files) = grep { /\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)\z/ } glob '"*"';
```

or simply:

```
my(@files) =  glob '"*.jpeg" "*.jpg" "*.gif" "*.png"';
```

Comment: What about `glob qq("$ARGV[0]/*.{jpeg,jpg,gif,png}")`? (Although this will break if the directory name contains double quotes. As your solution is now, you have to `chdir` into the `$ARGV[0]` directory to make the glob work)